# Heroku run command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When I am executing anything with "heroku run..." I get the following error:

```
/Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb:48:in `<class:GemNotFoundException>': undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1235:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
from /Users/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:9:in `<main>'
```

It was working fine earlier.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled rubygems downloading the .zip and doing ruby setup.rb and everything was fixed.